Azure Storage Files: Issue Generating SAS for a Directory
I'm trying to generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for a directory in Azure Storage File. Below is the code I'm using to create the SAS:
ShareSasBuilder sasBuilder = new ShareSasBuilder
{
    Resource = "s",
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
};
sasBuilder.SetPermissions(ShareFileSasPermissions.Read);

string containerProjectsName = "projects";

string directoryPath = "folder 0/folder 1";

var storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXXXX;AccountKey=XXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

ShareFileClient shareFileClient = new ShareFileClient(storageConnectionString, containerProjectsName, directoryPath);

var uri = shareFileClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);

return Results.Ok(uri);

When I use the generated link, for example:
https://storagepocv2.file.core.windows.net/projects/folder%200/folder%201?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T10%3A25%3A06Z&se=2024-12-19T10%3A30%3A06Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=xxxxxx

And try it in a browser or Postman, I receive the following error:
<Error>
  <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
  <Message>
    The specified resource does not exist.
    RequestId:955d2d79-901a-0047-1400-52b616000000
    Time:2024-12-19T10:25:13.4746276Z
  </Message>
</Error>

From my research, it seems like the ShareFileClient is intended for individual files rather than directories. However, I need a SAS that grants access to an entire directory (including all files and subdirectories).
Would really appreciate any tips or ideas!
What I’ve tried:

Checked that the directory and files exist using Azure Storage Explorer.
Tried creating a SAS for a single file, and that worked fine.
Tried changing the Resource from "s" to "f," but no luck.

Questions:

Is there a way to generate a SAS for an entire directory in Azure Storage File?
If not, what’s the best way to allow access to all files in a directory using SAS?


What actually you want? You need sas token for particular directory and you need access all files?

The goal is to allow users to download an entire folder with all files, subdirectories, and the folder hierarchy intact, while keeping the Azure Storage File private. Essentially, the user should be able to download the folder, and the folder structure should remain intact with all nested directories and files.


Azure Storage Files: Issue Generating SAS for a Directory

As of now, It is not possible to generate a SAS token that limits access specifically to a directory. SAS tokens can only be created to grant access to an entire file share or to individual files, but not to a directory within the share.

However, I need a SAS that grants access to an entire directory
(including all files and subdirectories).

You can use the below code that create SAS URL for the particular directory and subdirectory with all files using Azure .NET SDK.
Code:
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;

namespace AzureFilesDirectorySas
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Azure Storage connection details
            string storageConnectionString = "your connection string";
            string shareName = "share1";       // Replace with your file share name
            string directoryPath = "sample/demo";   // Replace with your directory path

            // Generate SAS for files in the directory
            List<Uri> sasUris = await GenerateSasForDirectoryAsync(storageConnectionString, shareName, directoryPath);

            // Output SAS URIs
            Console.WriteLine("SAS URIs for files in the directory:");
            foreach (var uri in sasUris)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uri);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<List<Uri>> GenerateSasForDirectoryAsync(string connectionString, string shareName, string directoryPath)
        {
            ShareDirectoryClient directoryClient = new ShareDirectoryClient(connectionString, shareName, directoryPath);

            // List to store SAS URIs
            List<Uri> sasUris = new List<Uri>();

            if (!await directoryClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Directory '{directoryPath}' does not exist.");
                return sasUris;
            }

            // Recursive helper function to list files and generate SAS URIs
            async Task ListFilesRecursivelyAsync(ShareDirectoryClient dirClient)
            {
                await foreach (ShareFileItem item in dirClient.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync())
                {
                    if (item.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        // Recursively handle subdirectories
                        ShareDirectoryClient subDirClient = dirClient.GetSubdirectoryClient(item.Name);
                        await ListFilesRecursivelyAsync(subDirClient);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ShareFileClient fileClient = dirClient.GetFileClient(item.Name);

                        var sasBuilder = new ShareSasBuilder
                        {
                            Resource = "f", // File resource
                            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1), // Set SAS expiration
                        };
                        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(ShareFileSasPermissions.Read); // Set desired permissions

                        // Generate the SAS URI
                        Uri fileSasUri = fileClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
                        sasUris.Add(fileSasUri);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Start the recursive listing from the root directory
            await ListFilesRecursivelyAsync(directoryClient);

            return sasUris;
        }
    }
}

Output:
SAS URIs for files in the directory:
https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/share1/sample/demo/test/13-xxx.html?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T11%3A31%3A24Z&se=2024-12-19T12%3A31%3A24Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=redacted
https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/share1/sample/demo/test/2024-12-09 08_26_37-SuccessFxxxx.png?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T11%3A31%3A24Z&se=2024-12-19T12%3A31%3A24Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=redacted
https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/share1/sample/demo/test/sxx.pdf?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T11%3A31%3A24Z&se=2024-12-19T12%3A31%3A24Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=redacted
https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/share1/sample/demo/25-11-2xx.html?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T11%3A31%3A24Z&se=2024-12-19T12%3A31%3A24Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=redacted
https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/share1/sample/demo/25-xxx.html?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T11%3A31%3A24Z&se=2024-12-19T12%3A31%3A24Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=redacted
https://venkat326123.file.core.windows.net/share1/sample/demo/team.xlsx?sv=2025-01-05&st=2024-12-19T11%3A31%3A24Z&se=2024-12-19T12%3A31%3A24Z&sr=f&sp=r&sig=redacted


Reference:
ShareSasBuilder Class (Azure.Storage.Sas) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn

Thanks for the clarification! I didn’t know it wasn’t possible to generate a SAS for a directory directly. I’ll give your approach a try using the Azure .NET SDK to create a SAS URL for the directory and its subdirectories.
I’ll test it out and update here to let you know if it works. Appreciate the help!

Thanks for the suggestion! The approach makes sense, but I'm concerned about performance with large volumes of files.
The goal is to allow users to download an entire folder with all files, subdirectories, and the folder hierarchy intact, while keeping the Azure Storage File private. Essentially, the user should be able to download the folder, and the folder structure should remain intact with all nested directories and files. Any suggestions for more efficient handling, like batching or other approaches?
Thanks again for your help!

Yes you can use batch processing like Process directories and files in parallel using Task.WhenAll or other asynchronous approaches and Paginate large directories using ShareDirectoryClient.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync()
